# Sequelize insert no erro on duplicated key

Tags: sequelize.js

Made this code to understand M:N relationship. The idea is simple, PK is formed from 2 FKs from other tables.

Checked on MySQL table is Ok, constrains are Ok, the only question is, the duplicated Add on PK for relation is not being included (working as intended) but also not throwing an error.

Code bellow:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const Model = Sequelize.Model

const path = 'mysql://myuser:mypass@localhost:3306/dbtest';

const sequelize = new Sequelize(path, {
  logging: false
});

class PostTag extends Model { }

/*
PostTag.init({
  postId: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    unique: "postTagConstraint"
  },
  tagId: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    unique: "postTagConstraint"
  }
}, { sequelize, modelName: 'post_tag' });
*/

class Post extends Model { }
Post.init({
  title: Sequelize.STRING,
  text: Sequelize.STRING
}, { sequelize, modelName: 'post' });

class Tag extends Model { }
Tag.init({
  name: Sequelize.STRING,
  status: Sequelize.STRING
}, { sequelize, modelName: 'tag' });

/*
Post.belongsToMany(Tag, {
  through: {
    model: PostTag
  },
  foreignKey: 'postId'
});

Tag.belongsToMany(Post, {
  through: {
    model: PostTag
  },
  foreignKey: 'tagId'
});
*/

Post.belongsToMany(Tag, { through : 'PostTag' });
Tag.belongsToMany(Post, { through : 'PostTag' });

async function Add() {
  let tag1 = await Tag.create({ name: 'Nice', status: 'Funcional' });
  let tag2 = await Tag.create({ name: 'Bad', status: 'Not working' });

  //console.log(tag1.name);
  //console.log(tag2.name);

  let post1 = await Post.create({ title: 'A very nice post', text: 'This is post1' });
  let post2 = await Post.create({ title: 'Toxic post', text: 'This is post2' });

  //console.log(`${post1.title} - ${post1.text}`);
  //console.log(`${post2.title} - ${post2.text}`);

  await post1.addTags([tag1, tag2]);
  await post2.addTags([tag2]);

  let res1 = await Post.findAll({ where: { id: 1 }, include: [Tag] });

  res1.forEach(p => {
    console.log(`${p.title} - ${p.text}`)

    p.tags.forEach(t => console.log(`${t.name} - ${t.status}`));
  });

  // No error being throw on duplicated
  await post2.addTags([tag1, tag2]);
}

sequelize.sync({ force: true }).then(() => {
  Add();

  console.log('It shall be one!');
});
```

As you can see I forced another Add with both one valid and one invalid, valid one is being inserted, duplicated one ignored SILENTLY. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be crystal clear if you analyze generated `SQL`.

What `.addTags` does is `UPDATE` operation for foreign key value of target data.

So, it will simply overwrite previous foreign key value.

Let's say you have `Post (id1)` and `Tag (id1), Tag(id2)`.

If you call `Post.addTags([tag1])` then `Post.addTags([tag1, tag2])`,

the result will be `Post (id1)` and `Tag (id1, post_id1), Tag(id2, post_id1)`.

So if you want to disallow item with the same key, then you should set `unique constraint` on your `foreign key`.

Below is example code from [sequelize manual](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/models-definition.html).

```
 // Creating two objects with the same value will throw an error. The unique property can be either a
 // boolean, or a string. If you provide the same string for multiple columns, they will form a
 // composite unique key.
 uniqueOne: { type: Sequelize.STRING,  unique: 'compositeIndex' },
 uniqueTwo: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, unique: 'compositeIndex' },
```

In your case, it would look something like,

```
tag_id: {
 type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
 references: {
   model: 'Post',
   key: 'id',
 },
 unique: 'constraint name'
}
```

cause you're setting unique constraint on `tag_id`.

Comment: If you going to bash people for not following a practice, and I agree totally I should have analyzed the SQL, them tell them how to do so. Be pro active.